# Not getting exact key data from json php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am decoding a JSON in PHP. I want to show first category then the relative article link and then the title. Here is the PHP Code + Json Which I am trying..

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$json = '[{
    "article": "https://example.com",
    "category": "Cat2",
    "title" : "1the title Cat2"
}, {
    "article": "https://example.com",
    "category": "Cat1",
    "title" : "1the title Cat1"
}, {
    "article": "https://example.com",
    "category": "Cat1",
    "title" : "2the title Cat1"
}, {
    "article": "https://example.com",
    "category": "Cat2",
    "title" : "2the title Cat2"
}, {
    "article": "https://example.com",
    "category": "Cat1",
    "title" : "3the title Cat1"
}]';
$values = json_decode($json, true);

$res = [];
foreach ($values as $entry) {
  $category = $entry['category'];
  if (! array_key_exists($category, $res)) {
    $res[$category] = [];
  }
   $res[$category][] = $entry;
}

foreach($res as $category => $entry): ?>
  <h1><?= $category; ?></h1>
    <?php foreach($entry as $article): ?>
    <p><?= $entry['title']; ?></p>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**It returning array sometime and for now nothing...**

I want something like this...

```
<h1>Cat2</h1>
    <p>https://example.com</p>
<span>the title</span>
    <p>https://example.com</p>
<span>the title</span>
  <h1>Cat1</h1>
    <p>https://example.com</p>
<span>the title</span>
    <p>https://example.com</p>
<span>the title</span>
    <p>https://example.com</p>
<span>the title</span>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: `$entry['title']` should be `$article['article']`

Comment: "Undefined index: title" should have given you a hint.

Comment: @NigelRen you are right..

Comment: @NigelRen can i get these keys values without second foreach ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$json = '[{
    "article": "https://example.com",
    "category": "Cat2",
    "title" : "1the title Cat2"
}, {
    "article": "https://example.com",
    "category": "Cat1",
    "title" : "1the title Cat1"
}, {
    "article": "https://example.com",
    "category": "Cat1",
    "title" : "2the title Cat1"
}, {
    "article": "https://example.com",
    "category": "Cat2",
    "title" : "2the title Cat2"
}, {
    "article": "https://example.com",
    "category": "Cat1",
    "title" : "3the title Cat1"
}]';
$values = json_decode($json, true);

$res = [];
foreach ($values as $entry) {
  $category = $entry['category'];
  if (! array_key_exists($category, $res)) {
    $res[$category] = [];
  }
   $res[$category][] = $entry;
}

foreach($res as $category => $entry): ?>
  <h1><?= $category; ?></h1>
    <?php foreach($entry as $article): ?>
    <p><?= $article['article']; ?></p>
    <p><?= $article['title']; ?></p>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't just dump code...a good answer contains an explanation of what you have changed and - most importantly - why that solves the problem

Answer (score -1):

One solution would be to first parse the json and save data values in seperate variables. For example as you already did:

```
 foreach ($values as $entry) {
       $article = $entry->article;
       $category = $entry->category;
       $title = $entry->title; 

       //Keep the variables in an array called information                
       $information = array(
            array($article, $category, $title)
       );

       //Then you can show the results as you want. For example:
       echo '<br>';
       echo "article: ". $information[0][0]."<br>"." category : ".$information[0][1]."<br>"."title : ".$information[0][2]."<br>";
    
         
}
```

Comment: I see no point in using another variable here. And OP wants entries grouped by category. This doesn't solve OP's problem, which was a typo.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @gre_gor. You are absolutely right that we need entries to be groubed by category. It was an omission.